# How to kill warning message from sas

Tags: sas

I am using the proc expand command to interpolate missing price values of my dataset.  My code is shown as following. Because I dont want the program to interpolate value at the beginning and end of each month, so I add by name and month.

```
proc expand data=data out=data (drop = time);
by name month; convert price / method = step;
run;
```

However, becase I have lots of missing values at the beginning and end of each month. So SAS gives me lots of warning message and the program will stop when the log is full.  Can anyone tell me how to kill the warning message please.

```
NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
     name =40838 Transaction Date=12AUG2003
```

Comment: Are you mostly concerned about the program stopping when log is full?  It's easy to avoid that, though I'm not sure if you can avoid the warning message.

Comment: Yes  I dont care about the warning message as long as the program can continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the log filling up issue, you can have that part of your log written to an external file.

```
proc printto log="c:\temp\templog.txt";
run;
proc expand ... ;

proc printto;
run;
```

Then that proc's statements go to that external file (Wherever you put it).

Comment: Great.  Thanks a lot.